# Rails nested forms not rendering a proper name or id for the inputs

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to render a nested form but the main problem is that the inputs generated haven't got a proper id/name. They should contain something like *_attributes but they don't.

Main model - Menu model

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :company
  
  has_many :menu_days, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :menu_days, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dishes
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations

  paginates_per 10

end
```

Nested model - MenuDay model

```
class MenuDay < ApplicationRecord
  
  belongs_to :menu

  validates :day, presence: true
end
```

New action in menus controller

```
def new
  @menu = Menu.new
  @frequencies = @@frequencies

  @@menu_days.each do |menu_day|
    @menu.menu_days.build(:day => menu_day.day)
  end
end
```

New.html.erb

```
<% menu.menu_days.each do |menu_day| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :menu_days, menu_day do |menu_days_form| %>
    <div>
      <%= menu_days_form.check_box :day, class: "form-checkbox-nutri" %>
      &nbsp;
      <%= menu_days_form.label :day, menu_day.day %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This code is rendering the nested form, but the inputs code are something like this:

```
<div>
  <input name="menu[menu_days][day]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="form-checkbox-nutri" type="checkbox" value="1" name="menu[menu_days][day]" id="menu_menu_days_day">
  &nbsp;
  <label for="menu_menu_days_day">Daily</label>
</div>
```

According to what I've read in the official documentation (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms), names and ids should contain _attributes suffix. Besides, they should contain as well some kind of unique id. To sum up, they should be something like menu[menu_days_attributes][0][day]. But, as you can see, they're not.

Also I already tried with more basic fields_for implementations with same result. For instance (avoiding the external loop):

```
<%= f.fields_for :menu_days do |menu_days_form| %>
  <div>
    <%= menu_days_form.check_box :day, class: "form-checkbox-nutri" %>
    &nbsp;
    <%= menu_days_form.label :day %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In this case, it didn't even iterate properly and it only showed 1 block instead of 8.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is, but if you are looking for the _attributes suffix then it will be added in the params. For example: `menu_day_attributes: [...]`

Comment: It won't. If I send the form, it is sent in the same way the HTML code has been rendered, with the input names without the _attributes suffix and without any kind of unique id. Anyway, thanks for answering.